# sending udp packet hangs

Tags: linux, network-programming, netcat

On a Linux (Ubuntu 16.04) box with no listener on port 8095, I type this

```
echo 1 | nc -u -w 1 127.0.0.1 8095
```

and the command does not return.  On my workstation (Ubuntu 17.10), where also nothing listens on 8095, NC returns immediately, which is what I'd expect.

Something similar has been asked [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/498880/nc-netcat-hangs-waiting-for-more-data-in-udp-mode) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43530294/netcat-udp-connection-hang-inside-udp-conatiner) without a good explanation.  One person suggests that switching from NC to socat solved his problem.  (I haven't tested that.)  Another notes that the -v flag to NC solves his problem, which I confirm works for me.  (The return code is 1 rather than 0, but it does return.)

Can anyone help me understand why this might be happening (and only on some hosts) and why the -v flag might change the behavior?

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: This seems more like a `netcat` specific problem than a generic Linux problem. Are you using the same version of `netcat` for the different distribution versions?

Comment: Hmm, yes, this happens on ubuntu 16.04 hosts and not on 17.10 hosts.  So I do suspect that theory is reasonable.

Comment: In that case, since it's fixed in the version of nc (1.105) in ubuntu 16.04 vs 1.178 in 17.10, it doesn't seem like there's even a bug report to file against netcat.  But filed [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netcat/+bug/1751550)